# Can't display full heigh when absolute positioning used

Tags: css, popup, absolute

I have a popup on mosueover. When it is placed in a div with absolute positioning, only part of the popup shows. My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/0eedc95a/2/) is here. This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142749/hover-popup-causes-main-div-to-expand). When I posted that question, I didn't realize the code would be used in a div that already has absolute positioning. In the fix posted in that thread, you can see the popup displays fine. The only differences between it and my new code is the addition of the two surrounding div's. They have height settings of 220px and I see that that is what is limiting the popup but I don't see how to fix it. Those initial height settings need to stay as they are so I can't remove or change them. Would someone help with that, please?

```
    <style>
    #ds-holder { 
     position: relative; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width: 300px; 
     height: 220px; 
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    .ds-container {
     top: 0px; 
     left: 0px; 
     width: 140px; 
     height: 220px; 
     position: absolute; 
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    #dsspan{
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
     border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
     color: #717171;
     font-size: 13px;
     height: auto;
     width: auto;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     line-height: 30px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     top: 80px;
     left:30px;
     display:none;
     padding:0 20px;
    }
    #dsspan:after{
     content:'';
     position:absolute;
     bottom:-10px;
     height:0px;
    }  
    .ds {border:1px solid red}
    .ds:hover #dsspan { display:block; }
    </style>

    <div id="ds-holder">
      <div class="ds-container">
        <div class="ds">
          <span id="dsspan">
           This line is longer than the rest.
           <ul>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
           </ul>  
          </span>
          <a href="example.com">Hover Here</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden` from `ds-holder` and `ds-container`?

Comment: That did fix the problem in the example. Unfortunately, I can't use it in the real code. That code uses the jssor slider to display an image and it needs the overflow set to hidden. I looked at many, many examples on the web and it seems the only way to show a popup like this is by using absolute positioning. So I ended up using a javascript link to open a dialog. It works but doesn't appear like I want but it allows the mouseover so I guess that is the only choice. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

In absolute position use `left: 0` and `right: 0` together to make full width.